# Batch file closes after user presses enter

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The following code is supposed to do a division computation. It should ask the user to enter the first number, wait for input, and then repeat with the second number.

(Some extra info: The user is NOT allowed to enter the number 22 or 0)

So far, after you enter the first number it exits on me. I have no idea why.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
@echo off
cls

:START
set /p FN = Enter first number: 
if %FN% == 22 GOTO EXIT
GOTO SECONDNUMBER


:EXIT
exit /b

:SECONDNUMBER
set /p SN = Enter second number: 
if "%SN%" == 22 exit /b
if "%SN%" == 0 GOTO ZEROERROR

GOTO DIVIDE


:ZEROERROR
echo Sorry! You CAN NOT divide by ZERO. Please enter a new number.
pause
cls
GOTO SECONDNUMBER

:DIVIDE
set /a RESULT = %FN%/%SN%
echo %FN% divided by %SN% = %RESULT%
pause
cls
GOTO START
```

Comment: `set /p SN = ...` sets a variable called `SN`+_space_. `if "%SN%" == 22` compares a quoted string with an unquoted one and will therefore always fail (the quotes are part of the comparison); to solve that, quote the right part as well (`"22"`); the quoted syntax is robust against empty strings, but the unquoted one is not.

Comment: I think we have answered this same problem every day this week.  Same with delayed expansion.  Probably the two most common errors with batch files that people do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```bat
@echo off
Title Division Computation
:START
cls
Color 0A
set /p "FN=Enter first number : "
if "%FN%" EQU "22" Exit
::*******************************
:SECONDNUMBER
Color 0A
set /p "SN=Enter second number : " 
if "%SN%" EQU "22" Exit
if "%SN%" EQU "0" GOTO ZEROERROR
GOTO DIVIDE
::*******************************
:DIVIDE
set /a RESULT=%FN% / %SN%
echo %FN% divided by %SN% = %RESULT%
pause
cls
GOTO START
::*******************************
:ZEROERROR
Color 0C
echo Sorry! You CAN NOT divide by ZERO. Please enter a new number.
pause
cls
GOTO SECONDNUMBER
::*******************************
```

And this is a bonus ***Calculator with a TypeWriter and Speaking Voice*** from me to you just for fun :)

```bat
@echo off
Title Calculator with a TypeWriter and Speaking Voice by Hackoo 2016
Color 0A & Mode con cols=80 lines=3
Call :TypeWriter "Hello, Welcome to my calculator. First off would you like to tell me your name ? "
echo(
Call :TypeWriter "So, Whats your name ? "
set /p name=
Call :TypeWriter "Ah, Nice to meet you %name% !"
::*************************************************************
:start
Call :TypeWriter "What is the first number you want to use ? "
set /p no=
Call :TypeWriter "What Operation do you want to use ? "
set /p op=
Call :TypeWriter "What is the second number you would like to use ? "
set /p no2=
Call :TypeWriter "%no% %op% %no2% "
set /a ans=%no% %op% %no2%
Call :TypeWriter " Well, That was an easy one the answer is %no% %op% %no2% = %ans% "
Call :TypeWriter " Would you like to do another calculaton ? Y(Yes) or N(No) ?"
set /p Question=
If /I "%Question%"=="Y" (goto :start) else (Goto :end)
::*************************************************************
:TypeWriter
Cls
echo(
(
echo strText=wscript.arguments(0^)
echo intTextLen = Len(strText^)
echo intPause = 150
echo For x = 1 to intTextLen
echo     strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1^)
echo     WScript.StdOut.Write strTempText
echo     WScript.Sleep intPause
echo Next
echo Set Voice=CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice"^)
echo voice.speak strText
)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
@cscript.EXE /noLogo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"
exit /b
::**************************************************************
:end
Exit
::*************************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you! You made me realize the issue was I had spaces in between my '=' signs. Once I removed them everything worked fine!